# Error when calling os.rename(): "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: python, pdf, text, ppm

I'm trying to use the script [in this wonderful medium post](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-files-bfefa4b21a67) to scrape some text out of a bunch of pdf's. I'm getting an error in the pdf_extract function on os.rename() that reads as follows:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\somepath\someppmfilename.ppm' -> 'C:\somepath\image0-0.ppm'"

But I can't figure out where this file is being opened. Any tips?

```
def pdf_extract(myFile, i PATH):        
    print("extracting from file:", myFile)        
    delete_ppms(PATH)        
    images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(PATH + myFile, output_folder=PATH)        
    j = 0        
    for file in sorted (os.listdir(PATH)): 
         if '.ppm' in file and 'image' not in file:
              os.rename(PATH + myFile, PATH + 'image' + str(i) + v'-' + str(j) + '.ppm'
              j += 1
    j = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Choose Start→Type to search "Resource Monitor"
In CPU tab find "Associated Handles"
Search your process path

How to open Resource Monitor.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor

Comment: Does this explain to you >.<